# Почему данные не сохроняются в Realm классе

Tags: android, retrofit, realm

```
public class InfoClient extends RealmObject implements Parcelable {

@PrimaryKey
@SerializedName("id")
private String id;
@SerializedName("phone")
private String phone;
@SerializedName("dop_phone")
private String dopPhone;
@SerializedName("email")
private String email;
@SerializedName("name")
private String name;
@SerializedName("city")
private String city;
@SerializedName("address")
private String address;
@SerializedName("user_type")
private String userType;

public InfoClient() {
}

public InfoClient(@NonNull String id,@NonNull String phone,@NonNull String dopPhone,
                  @NonNull String email,@NonNull String name,@NonNull String city,
                  @NonNull String address,@NonNull String userType) {
    this.id = id;
    this.phone = phone;
    this.dopPhone = dopPhone;
    this.email = email;
    this.name = name;
    this.city = city;
    this.address = address;
    this.userType = userType;
}

public InfoClient(Parcel in) {
    id = in.readString();
    phone = in.readString();
    dopPhone = in.readString();
    email = in.readString();
    name = in.readString();
    city = in.readString();
    address = in.readString();
    userType = in.readString();
}

@NonNull
public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(@NonNull String id) {
    this.id = id;
}
@NonNull
public String getPhone() {
    return phone;
}

public void setPhone(@NonNull String phone) {
    this.phone = phone;
}

@NonNull
public String getDopPhone() {
    return dopPhone;
}

public void setDopPhone(@NonNull String dopPhone) {
    this.dopPhone = dopPhone;
}

@NonNull
public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(@NonNull String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

@NonNull
public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(@NonNull String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

@NonNull
public String getCity() {
    return city;
}

public void setCity(@NonNull String city) {
    this.city = city;
}

@NonNull
public String getAddress() {
    return address;
}

public void setAddress(@NonNull String address) {
    this.address = address;
}

@NonNull
public String getUserType() {
    return userType;
}

public void setUserType(@NonNull String userType) {
    this.userType = userType;
}


public static final Creator<InfoClient> CREATOR = new Creator<InfoClient>() {

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public InfoClient createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new InfoClient(in);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public InfoClient[] newArray(int size) {
        return new InfoClient[size];
    }
};

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeString(id);
    dest.writeString(phone);
    dest.writeString(dopPhone);
    dest.writeString(email);
    dest.writeString(name);
    dest.writeString(city);
    dest.writeString(address);
    dest.writeString(userType);
}
```

}

```
ApiInterface apiInterface = ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);
            Call<AuthResponse> call =  apiInterface.auth(number,password);
            call.enqueue(new Callback<AuthResponse>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<AuthResponse> call, Response<AuthResponse> response) {
                        AuthResponse authorization = response.body();
                        DataAuth dataAuth = authorization.getData().get(0);
                        boolean success = dataAuth.isSuccess();
                        final InfoClient infoClient = dataAuth.getInfoClients();
                        Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
                        realm.beginTransaction();
                        realm.deleteAll();
                        realm.copyToRealm(infoClient);
                        realm.commitTransaction();
                        if (success) {
                            loadingView.hideLoading();
                            session.setLoggedin(true);
                            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), MarketMobileActivity.class);
                            intent.putExtra("infoClient",infoClient);
                            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                            startActivity(intent);
                            getActivity().finish();
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            eTxtUsername.setText("");
                            eTxtPassword.setText("");
                        }

                }
```

ввыводить ошибку

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo
```

Comment: Тому может быть много причин. В вашей ошибке далее есть подробная инфа

Comment: На какой строке ошибка и что в ней написано далее

Comment: При авторизации в класс InfoClient должен записаться данные клиента полученный из сервера.Следующий активити должен взять данные не сервера а из класса InfoClient.

Comment: Думаю проблема здесь 'Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
                        realm.beginTransaction();
                        realm.deleteAll();
                        realm.copyToRealm(infoClient);
                        realm.commitTransaction();
'